# Captcha image - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha

I'm in the process of making my own Captcha check on my website.
Everything's working, except I need some blurryness/effects on my text that's not viewable by a webcrawler etc.

Some of the code used to generate the text on the image:

```
Bitmap BitMap = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(BitMap);
g.DrawString(""+RandomNumberString+"", new Font("Tahoma", 40), Brushes.Khaki, new PointF(1, 1));
pictureBox1.Image = BitMap;
```

Example:

[image]

What can I do to get my effects/blurryness on my text?

Thank you!

Comment: Just in case you're looking for a complete solution - http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html

Comment: Thank you!
But i've already got a complete solution ready to use.
I would very much like to code my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://forum.coolwebawards.com/threads/7-Captcha-in-C-.NET). There you will find a code example on how to create a CAPTCHA using C# and the `DrawString` method.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: That's a very nice tutorial.. Thank you!

Comment: @CanÜrek: Thank you. As an alternative you can use the following code here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sample-of-a-simple-Captcha-f8c75c43

Answer (score 3):

Why roll out your own captcha when [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) is free, accessible (through the audio option, making it usable for people with visual issues) and at the same time helps digitize various publications? There's even a [.NET implementation](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html).

**Edit:**

Seeing how it's for fun, having a look at "[An ASP.NET Framework for Human Interactive Proofs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972952.aspx)" might give you some good ideas. Especially the [ImageHipChallenge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972952.aspx#hip_aspnet_topic6) as it includes image distortion code examples.

For example:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        int newX = (int)(x + (distortion * Math.Sin(Math.PI * y / 64.0)));
        int newY = (int)(y + (distortion * Math.Cos(Math.PI * x / 64.0)));
        if (newX < 0 || newX >= width) newX = 0;
        if (newY < 0 || newY >= height) newY = 0;
        b.SetPixel(x, y, copy.GetPixel(newX, newY));
    }
}
```

Which will move the pixels in a wave like fashion. Such as in the second word of your example.

Comment: Because then I would be depending on reCAPTCHA's servers being up all the time.
I would like to make it local to my server.

Comment: Is it worth the trade off though? Will your site for example be as accessible to visually impaired people as it would have been with reCAPTCHA? Which supports audio verification aswell? Sites such as Facebook and Ticketmaster [trust](http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/b6711e4394970d06) reCAPTCHA not to go down for example and they've got a very beefy setup on their side.

Comment: The part with the audio verification isn't important at the moment - 
The important part here is the text itself.
The "easy" solution isn't always the "fun" solution to make.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this for about 5 years and it doesn't involve any integration with horrid 3rd party APIs.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CaptchaImage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(! IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadCaptcha();[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    }
    
}

public void LoadCaptcha()
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap objBitmap = new Bitmap(130, 60);
        Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap);
        objGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
        Random objRandom = new Random();
        objGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, objRandom.Next(0, 50), objRandom.Next(10, 30), objRandom.Next(0, 200), objRandom.Next(0, 50));
        objGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, objRandom.Next(0, 20), objRandom.Next(0, 20), objRandom.Next(50, 80), objRandom.Next(0, 20));
        objGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, objRandom.Next(0, 20), objRandom.Next(10, 50), objRandom.Next(100, 200), objRandom.Next(0, 80));
        Brush objBrush =
            default(Brush);
        //create background style  
        HatchStyle[] aHatchStyles = new HatchStyle[]
        {
            HatchStyle.BackwardDiagonal, HatchStyle.Cross, HatchStyle.DashedDownwardDiagonal, HatchStyle.DashedHorizontal, HatchStyle.DashedUpwardDiagonal, HatchStyle.DashedVertical,
                HatchStyle.DiagonalBrick, HatchStyle.DiagonalCross, HatchStyle.Divot, HatchStyle.DottedDiamond, HatchStyle.DottedGrid, HatchStyle.ForwardDiagonal, HatchStyle.Horizontal,
                HatchStyle.HorizontalBrick, HatchStyle.LargeCheckerBoard, HatchStyle.LargeConfetti, HatchStyle.LargeGrid, HatchStyle.LightDownwardDiagonal, HatchStyle.LightHorizontal
        };
        ////create rectangular area  
        RectangleF oRectangleF = new RectangleF(0, 0, 300, 300);
        objBrush = new HatchBrush(aHatchStyles[objRandom.Next(aHatchStyles.Length - 3)], Color.FromArgb((objRandom.Next(100, 255)), (objRandom.Next(100, 255)), (objRandom.Next(100, 255))), Color.White);
        objGraphics.FillRectangle(objBrush, oRectangleF);
        //Generate the image for captcha  
        string captchaText = string.Format("{0:X}", objRandom.Next(1000000, 9999999));
        //add the captcha value in session  
        Session["CaptchaVerify"] = captchaText;
        Font objFont = new Font("Courier New", 15, FontStyle.Bold);
        //Draw the image for captcha  
        objGraphics.DrawString(captchaText, objFont, Brushes.Black, 20, 20);
        //  objBitmap.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
        byte[] _bytes;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            objBitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            _bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
        imgcaptcha.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(_bytes);
        ImageCapchaSubmit.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(_bytes);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
   
}
```